# Update @ViewScoped bean from JAX-RS service

Tags: jax-rs, cdi, jsf-2.2, view-scope

I've got a mishmash of JAX-RS webservices and JSF/CDI beans. Usual display of my `@Entity`s is from a `@ViewScoped` JSF bean collecting relevant entities in a `@PostConstruct` method:

```
@Named @ViewScoped
public class Manager {
    private List<MyEntity> entities; // + getter
    private MyEntity instance; // + getter/setter

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
         entities = collectEntities();
         instance = new MyEntity();
    }

    public void save() {
         instance = persistInstance();
         entities.add(instance);
    }
    // additional methods like collectEntities, persistInstance
}
```

Normal operation can call `manager.save` to persist a new entity and display it alongside the old ones.

Now, a JAX-RS service can also create entities that should be in the collection managed by such a scoped bean:

```
@Path("/myentity")
public class MyEntityService {
    @PersistenceContext EntityManager em;

    @PUT
    public Response save(@FormParam("name") String name) {
         MyEntity entity = new MyEntity(name);
         em.persist(entity);
         return Response.ok(entity.getId()).build();
    }
}
```

The service can be called on a page where there's also a `manager` instance.

My **question** is: how can I make the existing `manager` instance aware of the additional entity, so that a JSF ajax re-render of a `manager.entities` list will include the entity created by the webservice?

So far, **I've tried** a CDI event observed by the CDI bean. The event gets fired from the service but is never received by the bean.

As a **workaround** I can fire a JSF ajax function telling the `manager` to refresh it's entity list (leveraging `<a4j:jsFunction action="#{manager.init()}">`, for example). However I'm unsure about the implications: will this expose a timing problem when the user asks for the entity list to be displayed earlier than the initialization can complete (the list isn't shown by default)?

As a **total hack** I can probably grab the bean from the session in the service and punch my data in. I shudder just thinking about it.

Answer (score 0):

View scope is something that is JSF specific, as a JSF specific CDI context.  It is alive only within the scope of the given view.  JAX-RS has no specific way that I can think of to access this scope.  I don't believe view scope would even have access to the HTTP request.

Comment: For the last part: `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest()` returns the `HttpServletRequest`. And since I get the `JSESSIONID` for the user via cookie, I even have his session.